# Can the same Redis instance be used manually alongside kue.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, kue

I am using kue.js, which is a redis-backed priority queue for node, for pretty straightforward job-queue stuff (sending mails, tasks for database workers).

As part of the same application (albeit in a different service), I now want to use redis to manually store some mappings for a url-shortener. **Does concurrent manual use of the same redis instance and database as kue.js interfere with kue, i.e., does kue require exclusive access to its redis instance?**

Or can I use the same redis instance manually as long as I, e.g., avoid certain key prefixes?

I do understand that I could use multiple databases on the same instances but found a lot of chatter from various sources that discourage the use of the database feature as well as talk of it being deprecated in the future, which is why I would like to use the same database for now if safely possibly.

Any insight on this as well as considerations or advice why this might or might not be a bad idea are very welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am not too late with this answer, I just came across this post ...

It should be perfectly safe.  See the [README](https://github.com/Automattic/kue/blob/master/Readme.md), especially the section [on redis connections](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#redis-connection-settings).

You will notice that each queue can have its own prefix (default is *q*), so as long as you are aware of how prefixes are used in your system, you should be fine.  I am not sure why it would be a bad idea as long as you know about the prefixes and load usage by various apps hitting the redis server.  Can you reference a post/page where this was described as a bad idea ?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late reply. I accepted your answer, because it concurs with what I found when using the same redis instance and DB as kuejs. No further problems.

The chatter about not using more than one database did not concern namespacing the same DB, but the multiple databases feature of Redis, and most of that talk was motivated by the fact that redis-cluster does not support multiple DB's (http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec).

I remember an _official_ statement that the multiple databases feature will not be deprecated however. But managing key-prefixes works just as fine.